# How dynamic change Referer CefSharp?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, http-referer

How dynamic change Referer in CefSharp?
My handler:

```
public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : ResourceRequestHandler
    {
        public static string Referer = Program.refererUrl;

        protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            request.SetReferrer(Referer, ReferrerPolicy.Origin);

            return CefReturnValue.Continue;
        }
    }

    public class CustomRequestHandler : RequestHandler, IRequestHandler
    {
        protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
        {
            return new CustomResourceRequestHandler();
        }
    }
```

And i change Referer in function:

```
string referer= browser.Address.ParseUrl();
CustomResourceRequestHandler.Referer = referer;
```

But it does not change, but that which was originally determined remains in Handler.

Comment: Did you assign browser.RequestHandler with a new instance of CustomRequestHandler?

Comment: Yes, Referer is defined, but dynamically in the code it does not change

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Have you attached the debugger and confirmed that SetReferrer is being called?

Comment: @amaitland Yes, SetReferer in the handler works, but when I try to change the Referer during the execution of the program, before calling LoadUrl, it does not change, but it remains the same

Comment: Is `SetReferrer` called with the url you expect? Is it a valid url?

Comment: Yes, url is valid.
SetReferer is called only in the handler, because it cannot be called just in the code from the browser object?

Comment: Is `SetReferrer` actually being called? You cannot call it directly. If `SetReferrer` is being called then this is probably a bug in [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues)

Comment: Yes, SetReferrer is indeed called, but the problem is that when I change the value of the Referer field by calling LoadUrl, then SetReferer uses the old value.
Can you tell me how you can call SetReferer directly from the code and not from the handler?

Comment: You cannot call `SetReferrer` directly. Your example is incomplete, there is no `LoadUrl` call. Start from the beginning what are you trying to achieve? The `Address` is the same [browser.MainFrame.Url](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_IFrame_Url.htm)

Comment: I do a loadurl for site A, first send it a Referer, then I follow the link from site A to site B and try to transfer Referer from site A url to site B.
But for some reason, for me, only SetReferer works for site A, but for site B it remains the same, that is, the same as site A

Comment: Start with something simpler, set a fix referrer for all requests, confirm that works. Confirm that works as expected.

Comment: Now this is exactly how it works, all sites have one Referer installed, I checked this.
But I need to dynamically replace it, and that's just it

Comment: I'd suggest adding some logging, likely something is happening in a different order to what you expect.

Comment: I solved the problem thanks, indeed, it was not the order of operations that I expected